# Long form of the MySQL client "ego" command, how to use it?

Tags: mysql

According to the reference manual, the MySQL client has the command:

> ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
>
> ...
>
> Each command has both a long and short form. The long form is not case sensitive; the short form is. The long form can be followed by an optional semicolon terminator, but the short form should not. [[source]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html)

I'm just playing around in the command line client and the \G form works:

```
select * from company \G
```

How would I use the long "ego" form if I wanted to?  Does it work in the command line client?  I just can't figure it out and Google isn't turning up anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find anything here? I'm looking for the same, and also not finding any examples. I am using the default command-line mysql client: $ mysql -V mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Comment: Unfortunately not. Post here if you do!

Answer (score 8):

Start MySQL client with --named-commands.

```
(none)>select 'hi'
    -> ego
*************************** 1. row ***************************
hi: hi
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ego` is available for command line only. By default queries are delimited using semicolons (`;`).  This applies to any API that connects to `mysql`.

Comment: ego - Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.

Comment: @osmosis, ego stands for "Extended GO"